# Auto-embed for soundcloud and grooveshark links

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

I've started a chat over here, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1703/the-sound-of-source-code which we can share music in, except the auto-embed code only works for youtube videos.

This may also be useful for any musical Stack Exchange sites out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no auto-embedding; even for YouTube videos. The YouTube onebox is just a still image from the video, with a link to the video's regular YouTube page.

We don't want any flash objects etc. in chat messages.