# Chat oneboxing support for Soundcloud?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, soundcloud

This is a bit of a silly request, but since SE has recently been posting their [Podcasts](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-18) on soundcloud, I feel like I now have a legitimate reason to bring this up.

Would implementing oneboxing support (a la facebook) for SoundCloud tracks be quite difficult?
Basically, similar to the way Wikipedia oneboxes, with a track title which links to the SoundCloud page, album art pulled from SoundCloud, and some track info (length, genre, title, tags) would be ideal.  Or, even just a static image linking to the track page would be nice to have.

Example ([click here for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmV1s.png)):

[image: Even a still image, like this would be useful]

What's great about Soundcloud is that they have an entire section of their site dedicated to [community developed apps](http://soundcloud.com/apps?ref=top) that use Soundcloud's API for all kinds of different things, and there's even an area [specifically for developers](http://developers.soundcloud.com/) for anyone looking to incorporate Soundcloud into their own app.

I don't know if any of that would actually be *useful* for this, but it still says something about the company.

Comment: For the record, I wasn't suggesting a flash auto-embed as was suggested in that linked question.  More of the youtube-style oneboxing we've seen already.

Comment: I agree, this approach is different (and is something I'd be more inclined to see added).

Comment: I'm not familiar with how facebook does this, but if Tim Stone's gonna jump off the bridge, then so will I!

Comment: [You have a bad track record with oneboxing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13070632#13070632). This isn't like [oneboxing rotten tomatoes for movies.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127579/), and oneboxes are already so annoying [someone made a userscript just so they could collapse them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203302/). If the goal is to allow you to advertise that you are listening to music, I cannot disagree more with implementing this.

Comment: We have a processing plugin for SoundCloud now, which we selectively turn on site per site as needed, embedding the player in a post. I'm going to look into what it would take to put this in chat.

Comment: @TimPost *bump*? :)

Answer (score 5):

I've made a userscript to do this.

The result? [Exactly as you imagined](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=5231335#5231335) :)

> [image]

It's based largely off my [Github oneboxer](https://stackapps.com/q/6535/26088), just modified to work for SoundCloud. It uses the SoundCloud API to get any relevant information and displays it in a pretty manner.

*This will only look good if the linked track has a description and possibly some tags; otherwise it will look very plain :/*

### You can install the userscript directly from [Github](https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-soundcloudOneboxer/raw/master/SE-SoundCloud-Oneboxer.user.js)

Or, view [the source code](https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-soundcloudOneboxer/blob/master/SE-SoundCloud-Oneboxer.user.js).

---

I think the advantage of having it as a userscript is that it *can* [embed the player](https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed) -- because if you want it, you choose to install it, *but* if SE did use [their processing plugin for SoundCloud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106425/chat-oneboxing-support-for-soundcloud#comment758284_106425) it would be better, because then everybody would be able to have oneboxed links! :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this!  I can't get it to work in chrome, though.  Installed it and enabled developer extensions and... nothing.  (I don't know much about this stuff.)

Comment: @GnomeSlice Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?utm_source=inline-install-disabled) and then clink the link 'from Github'. Tampermonkey will do everything else for you! :) You can find me in the Tavern if it doesn't work for you though :)

Comment: seems to not like tracks with a long list of tags. :P  http://puu.sh/lpsfq/09cbdeb3c8.png

Comment: I deleted it because it was making my webpage scroll further to the right every time a new message was posted.  It was in The Bridge (gaming room).

Comment: @GnomeSlice oh ok, see the Sandbox: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/sandbox, I've added a screenshot there to show it! (fixed!)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The SE Staff have decided not to embed things in chat, only to link to them. This answer is invalid.

Soundcloud has already released a way to embed links in web pages, so it shouldn't be hard to put it in chat.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/122750992"></iframe>
```

That is the code for their embedded player, why not embed it in chat? If Soundcloud is embedded like that, it will make it easier to listen to for the chat users.

(Note: I am in no way an employee of SE and am not representing them, just expressing my opinion.)

Comment: I don't think embedding the player directly into chat is a very good idea. I certainly don't want to be randomly downloading things because someone posted a Soundcloud link. It's bad enough people post links to animated GIF images...

Comment: The player doesn't involve downloading? (the GIF thing is true, except in some cases (showing off working code, etc)

Comment: It requires downloading an entire SWF file in addition to the information for the specific file. If it were *just* a static image and text, it wouldn't be so bothersome. Besides, they've already stated [they won't be embedding things in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103949/auto-embed-for-soundcloud-and-grooveshark-links/104007#104007).

Comment: @animuson ah. thanks for the correction. Do you want me to remove the question?

Comment: @animuson no? Should I take my answer down?

Comment: Doesn't require flash now anyway.

Comment: I've used the embed in my [userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268390/260841) :) +1