# Rotten Tomatoes OneBox for specific movie request

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Riding on how we now have a [Movie Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), I would like to request for a OneBox feature for [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/) for chat.

Doing a quick 5-min mock-up using Chrome's dev editor, I came up with a format like this:

[image]

**A**: The movie's score from the critics.
Other thoughts include a x%/y% where x = critic sore and y = audience score

**B**: The movie's title

**C**: The movie's poster image that is on their page.

**D**: The icon of whether or not it is 'rotten' or 'fresh'

**E**: The critic consensus (if there is one)

In order to properly OneBox the link should be like as follows:

`http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/MOVIE_NAME/`

For my example, Dark Knight, the link is:

`http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_dark_knight/`

While RottenTomatoes itself isn't a hugely useful site; people do use their reviews as a basis.  On top of this, we could also implement something for IMDB in a similar fashion, replacing the RT rating with IMDB's overall rating.

Comment: In this case I'd also propose IMDb one-boxing. Since it has a more neutral-referencial and less judging character.

Answer (score 4):

I would propose to use [**Metacritic**](http://metacritic.com) instead, they are also based on reviews by critics, set a higher standard (at least by the looks) and apply to more than just movies. This for instance allows The Bridge (Gaming.SE) to link Games. I believe that TV is usable for the SciFi.SE chat room and perhaps Music for Music.SE and AVP.SE, *just enable it everywhere*... :)

Comment: Problem I have personally with Metacritic is that it is too easily corrupted by anonymous users pushing down ratings and paid journalists pushing up the ratings.  For instance [Mass Effect 3](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/mass-effect-3).

Comment: @TylerShads: How does Rotten Tomatoes solve this? I see they have critics there too.

Comment: Not saying they solve this problem all together nor disagreeing with using Metacritic, I just don't personally like them >:).  But I do agree that might be a better solution for a general use instead of just movies.

Comment: There isn't an *official* API for Metacritic. But, there is an unofficial version: https://github.com/danger89/metacritic_api which