# Can we one-box imdb links in chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

For both Sci-Fi and Movies, IMDB is a pretty heavily used resource.  We also share links to different movies in chat, and it's not very apparent what those links are because they tend to look like this: [imdb.com/title/tt1456635](http://imdb.com/title/tt1456635).

A simple one-box would be an amazing feature to have and would benefit both sites.

Comment: To add input from Sci-fi: Make it so!

Comment: Maybe you should submit a `[feature-request]` to IMDb to use proper slugs in their URLs.

Comment: Just drop in the Amazon link. It's the same company now anyway

Comment: Possible alternative (un-declined) request you could support: [Rotten Tomatoes OneBox for specific movie request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127579/rotten-tomatoes-onebox-for-specific-movie-request)

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, ain't gonna happen. [IMDB doesn't allow it](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware).

Comment: BOOOOOO.... That stinks... :-\

Comment: [tag:status-thwarted]

Comment: Ahh, forgot about their policy on that.  Thanks for taking the time to read this though.