# Oneboxing for Spotify links in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I realise that Spotify could not directly be called a programming resource, but in some rooms we like to share songs quite frequently and a pleasing onebox would be much nicer than a bunch of truncated URLs.

*Good music is key to successful programming!*

It'd be no more prone to spamming than URLs, really; and I *like* that it's slightly more prominent.

---

#### Before

[image: Spotify URL in chat]

#### After

[image: Hypothetical Spotify oneboxing]

Comment: There was a similar [request here for soundcloud](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106425/chat-oneboxing-support-for-soundcloud) and based on the last comment of [Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106425/chat-oneboxing-support-for-soundcloud#comment758284_106425) maybe a 6-8 units estimate is available now and this request could be bundled with that earlier one.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a userscript to do this. It uses the Spotify API to get the information.

It looks [like this in Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4114811#4114811):

> [image]

---

I've actually made it as a 'plugin' for my [custom oneboxes userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6642/26088) at Stack Apps.

### You can install the custom onebox script [from GitHub](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/raw/master/custom-oneboxes.user.js)

All you need to do then is copy and paste the below code (a 'plugin') at the top, before the `----------------------------------------------` :)

```
customSites['play.spotify.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/spotify.css">');
    if(link.indexOf('album') > -1) {
        var album_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/"+album_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var image = d.images[0].url;
            var artist = d.artists[0].name;            
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='"+image+"'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                                <div class='artist'>"+artist+"</div> \
                            </div>";
            $obj.html(template);
        });
    } else if (link.indexOf('artist') > -1) {
        var artist_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"+artist_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var image = d.images[0].url;
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='"+image+"'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                            </div>";
            
            $obj.html(template);
        });        
    } else if (link.indexOf('track') > -1) {
        var track_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/"+track_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            var artist = d.artists[0].name;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQJQ0.png'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                                <div class='artist'>"+artist+"</div> \
                            </div>";
            
            $obj.html(template);
        });            
    }    
};
```

Comment: Hey, that's cool!